# remove dead jobs from nomad status

Tags: nomad

I was running a cron (periodic) job through nomad which ran every 30 sec, the job does nothing but just

`echo "some string"`

and hence ends immediately

when I do

`nomad status`

I get all the dead jobs also-- the jobs that have finished executing, which are useless to me. Is there some way to remove the dead jobs?

PS: one obvious solution is to grep out the dead jobs, any solution provided by nomad?

Comment: would be good to share your job spec here :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Dead/Completed jobs are cleaned up in accordance to the garbage collection interval.

You can force garbage collection using the [System API endpoint](https://www.nomadproject.io/api/system.html#force-gc) which will run the global garbage collector. The CURL command would look like:

`$ curl -X PUT http://localhost:4646/v1/system/gc`

If you wish to lower the GC interval permanently for jobs, you can use the [job_gc_threshold](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/agent/configuration/server.html#job_gc_threshold) configuration parameter within the server config stanza.

Comment: You can also run `nomad system gc` from the command line

Comment: Would GC remove a failed job from the jobs list though? Or just allocations? Im thinking "failed" may qualify as "dead".  We have a couple jobs that went missing(no longer showing in jobs list), and are trying to backtrace if it was from user intervention, or GC.